# It is OK leave removal of tag from DOM to another library?

Tags: jquery-isotope, riot.js

I'm testing riot with isotope.js. I add tags to an isotope container and when I want to remove them with collapsing animation I call isotope command "remove". This command removes the DOM object and I don't get a riot 'unmout' event which is fine as I don't need to remove any subscriptions/listeners etc.

I actually wrote my code to trap event "removeCompleted" triggered by isotope so that I would ask the tag to unmount itself but I realized the tag doesn't exist anymore at that point.

But is there any problem in using riot this way or should I aim for a proper tag lifecycle?

Comment: you could unmount them before removing them; not sure if `iso.on('removeComplete', function(removedItems) {...})` still refers to the DOM.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, I was not paying attention: removeCompleted will provide the list of removedItems (I was checking presence of the items using $("mytag") in the console)
The tags were removed from DOM but not destroyed.
So I just need to call unmount() on each item mentioned in the list and tag lifecycle will be respected.

Answer (score 0):

Answering specifically your question, there's no problem to mix riot.js with other libraries like your example isotope.js ...

He is not too much intrusive and you can mix with a lot of other libraries. But avoid use other libraries that do the same as riot.js do.